# How can I anchor a textbox in wpf?

Tags: wpf

I have a window with tabs. On one of the tabs, I have a layout like below. (In fact it is more complicated, I have 4 text boxes in a row, and I have more rows.) How can I make the 3rd textbox have the width of the label + the width of the text box above, that is, to have them properly aligned ? The problem is that WPF widens the 3rd textbox, when I type text into it. Using hardcoded numbers for the sizes defeats the whole purpose of WPF. I could do that way 10 times faster in Windows Forms than in WPF.

Is there a better way, than using a grid for each set of consecutive small text boxes, having to skip the large ones from the grid, because putting them in messes up everything.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="SmallTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Width="{Binding ElementName=grid,Path=ActualWidth}"
                Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="c1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="c2"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Foo:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBox}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Foobar:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                     Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBox}"/>
        </Grid>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>

        <Grid Name="grid2" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="c1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="c2"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Bar:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBox}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

EDIT: Here is the solution based on Julien Lebosquain's answer:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="SmallTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Width="{Binding ElementName=grid,Path=ActualWidth}">
        <Grid Name="grid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Foo:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBox}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Foobar:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                     Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBox}"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Bar:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
                     Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBox}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it backwards. It's not the largest textbox that messes up everything. It's the fact that the small textboxes have a fixed size that makes them not behave like the largest one. You've got a contradiction here: the use of a stack panel which means "takes the width of my children", `Width=Auto` that has the same behavior, but you don't want your stack panel to grow.

Somewhere higher in the visual tree, you need to either specify a width or use a control whose sizing behavior is to take the whole space, like Grid.

Personally, I'll go with this solution:

- Use only one inner grid, the small textboxes not having a fixed size anymore, and the large textbox having `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"`.
- Apply `Width="Auto"` to the first column and `Width="*"` to the second.
- Replace the existing `StackPanel` with a `Grid` having the first column fixed or star-sized (so that it will scale when the window is resized). Put your inner grid in this first column.

Comment: Thanks. Setting the second column's width to * did the trick. It works with a small glitch. I can use a single grid, but I need to keep the stackpanel, with the Width="{Binding ElementName=grid,Path=ActualWidth}".

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have one grid with 4 rows. And have a ColumnSpan on the 3rd row. It also means that you don't need the SharedSizeGroups.

```
<Grid Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Foo:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBox}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Foobar:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                 Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBox}"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

        <Label Content="Bar:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBox}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: This does not work. Typing some text in the 3rd textbox makes it wider.

Answer (score 0):

**Just remove Alignment properties:**

```
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
```

For example textbox would be:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtMyName1" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtMyName2" Margin="3" />
```